# Telerik RadDataGrid Xamarin, remove the column separators

Tags: xamarin, telerik

Can't figure out how to remove the 3 dots in each header column, can anyone tell me how to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently it's called the Options Button, and in later versions there is an

```
IsOptionsButtonVisible
```

Which can be set to false.

For some reason this isn't available in my current version so just setting

```
OptionsButtonText = string.Empty;
```

worked for me.